# php curl: return to login page

Tags: php, curl

I've been banging my head against this one.
I am trying to login to a page and using php and curl but having two issues and I suspect them to be related.

1. Cookie files remain empty (likely because of failed login?)
2. After trying to login the page returns to the login page with error: Login Time Exceeded.

First I go to the page to extract a time sensitive variable:

//$urlString = "https://domain.com/portal/gas.nsf/Tool?

```
OpenAgent&action=TNQuery&ordernumber=".$order."&tn=".$tn."&User=".$username."&lang=en_US";
    $loginUrl = 'https://domain.com/login';
    $randnum = rand(5, 15);
    $ckfile = tempnam ($cwd, "cookie.txt");



$ch = curl_init($loginUrl);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); //write
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//var_dump($result);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($result);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);

// extract time sensitive variable from the login page
$genData = $xml->xpath("//input[@name='pageGenTime']");
$epoch = $genData[0][value];
```

Data to post:

```
$postdata = array(
    'HiddenURI' => 'https://domain.com/loadPortal.htm',
    'AUTHMETHOD' => 'UserPassword',
    'pageGenTime' => $epoch,
    'LOCALE' => "en_US",
    'usr_name' => $username,
    'usr_password' => $password
);
```

cURL handlers:

```
$ch = curl_init();
// Now login to the portal
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $loginUrl,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $agent,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt'
));
curl_exec($ch);

$exec = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);
```

print_r returns:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://domain.com/login
    [content_type] => text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 253
    [request_size] => 304
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.08823
    [namelookup_time] => 2.7E-5
    [connect_time] => 3.1E-5
    [pretransfer_time] => 8.0E-5
    [size_upload] => 744
    [size_download] => 9992
    [speed_download] => 113249
    [speed_upload] => 8432
    [download_content_length] => 9992
    [upload_content_length] => 744
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.026516
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_ip] => 206.47.249.9
    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => [concealed]
    [local_port] => 41349
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Great, HTTP code 200.. but it's not actually logged in. 
What am I doing wrong? the POST data is correct.

Thank you for your valuable time!

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what the full response from the API is.  Just because you get a 200 doesn't mean the API call succeeded (if it is a poorly designed API that doesn't modify response codes).

Comment: How can I obtain the full response? The code above returns a html login page. Is there a way I can get the information we're are looking for @MikeBrant ?

Comment: I mean for example what do you get from `var_dump($exec)`? What is the API response itself telling you?

Comment: Figured out the issue, it was the cookies it did not like:  `  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt'`    changed to  `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $randnum.'cookie.txt',
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $randnum.'cookie.txt'` now the cookies are being written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue, it was the cookies it did not like:  `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt'` changed to  `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $randnum.'cookie.txt',
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $randnum.'cookie.txt'`.

Now the cookies are being written and the login succeeded.
The var_dump($exec) did provide extra debugging I needed. Thanks @mike-brant !